# Is it possible to change __repr__ of True to be False?

Tags: python, python-3.x, repr

I'm curious how can i change "True" to display "False" result, is it even possible?

```
True.__repr__() = False
True.__str__() = False
```

Only those primitive ideas came to my head

Comment: Do you have an end purpose in mind?

Comment: You cannot change the dunder methods of built-in types, but you can create a subclass and override `__repr__` there.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Just for the sake of making things more complicated?

Comment: Maybe with forbiddenfruit?

Comment: I'm doing exercise and wanted to be sneaky, anyway thx for answers

Comment: @Fr0glem This is not a proper way to be sneaky unless the only task you've been given is "Make as stupid and hard-to-understand code as you can"

Answer (score 1):

If you try setting `__str__` or `__repr__` to a different function, it will throw an error.

Example code:

```
def return_false():
    return False

True.__str__ = return_false

print(True.__str__())
```

This will throw an error

```
AttributeError: 'bool' object attribute '__str__' is read-only
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.X? I don't think so, you can't assign to the keyword `True` and the `__str__` and the `__repr__` methods are read-only. However, in Python 2, you can kind of do this in a given scope.

```
class FakeTrue(int):
    def __new__(cls):
        return super(FakeTrue, cls).__new__(cls, 1)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'False'

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'False'

True = FakeTrue()

print True # False
print type(True) # <class '__main__.FakeTrue'>

print 1 == 1 # True
print type(1 == 1) # <type 'bool'>
```

Notice that `int.__eq__` still returns the singleton `True` and was not overridden.